# Parse filename from full path using regular expressions in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How do I pull out the filename from a full path using regular expressions in C#?

Say I have the full path `C:\CoolDirectory\CoolSubdirectory\CoolFile.txt`.

How do I get out CoolFile.txt using the .NET flavor of regular expressions? I'm not really good with regular expressions, and my RegEx buddy and me couldn't figure this one out.

Also, in the course of trying to solve this problem, I realized that I can just use  `System.IO.Path.GetFileName`, but the fact that I couldn't figure out the regular expression is just making me unhappy and it's going to bother me until I know what the answer is.

Comment: It's fine you want to know how it _would work_ with regular expressions, but to make this world a better place, please promise that you'll use Path.* anyway :)

Comment: GetFileName may not be an option if you are working with [Long Path](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Long%20Path)

Comment: There are reasons for and against regex: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
//  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

/// <summary>
///  Regular expression built for C# on: Tue, Oct 21, 2008, 02:34:30 PM
///  Using Expresso Version: 3.0.2766, http://www.ultrapico.com
///  
///  A description of the regular expression:
///  
///  Any character that is NOT in this class: [\\], any number of repetitions
///  End of line or string
///  
///
/// </summary>
public static Regex regex = new Regex(
      @"[^\\]*$",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );
```

**UPDATE:** removed beginning slash

Comment: You realize that's going to get "\CoolFile.txt"

Comment: Good catch, didn't cross my mind that the slash wasn't supposed to be there when I tested it

Answer (score 40):

Why must you use regular expressions? .NET has the built-in `Path.GetFileName()` method specifically for this which works across platforms and filesystems.

Comment: You didn't read the question carefully.  He's aware of GetFileName(), but wants to know how to do it with reg ex.

Comment: When I posted my answer that sentence was not there.

Comment: Then feel free to ignore me.  :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's one approach:

```
string filename = Regex.Match(filename, @".*\\([^\\]+$)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Basically, it matches everything between the very last backslash and the end of the string. Of course, as you mentioned, using Path.GetFileName() is much easier and will handle lots of edge cases that are a pain to handle with regex.

Comment: +1 because I was able to solve a Perl regex issue with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Shorter:

```
string filename = Regex.Match(fullpath, @"[^\\]*$").Value;
```

Or:

```
string filename = Regex.Match(fullpath, "[^\\"+System.IO.Path.PathSeparator+"]*$").Value;
```

Without `Regex`:

```
string[] pathparts = fullpath.Split(new []{System.IO.Path.PathSeparator});
string file = pathparts[pathparts.Length-1];
```

The official library support you mentioned:

```
string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullpath);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\w+:\\(\w+\\)*(?<file>\w*\.\w*)
```

This obviously would need expanding to cover all path characters, but the named group "file" contains your filename for the example path given.

Comment: just curious, what does next group do? 
(?<file>\w*\.\w*).
should it be (?: )

Comment: @Artu: `(?<file>\w*\.\w*)` is a named capture group.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use the System.Path class. It will mean you will have to worry about less if you ever decide to support Mono/Linux (dlamblin's example takes the path seperator into account, but you may get a strange OS that has strange paths). The System.Path class can also combine two paths into one. So for example:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "My App Stuff");
```

would resolve to:

- Windows: C:\Documents and Settings\[User]\My Documents\My App Stuff
- Linux: /[User]/My App Stuff